# Why does my laptop always to to Wifi 4?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using Asus ROG laptop with Intel AX200 network card as below.

[image]

I have a router with Wifi 4/5 enable. My phone (Android 10, Redmi) can connect to Wifi 5 without any problem. However, my laptop always go to Wifi 4.

[image]

I already set the Preferred Band in Device Manager -> Network Devices as below.

Anyone can suggest me a fix? I am using Windows 10.

Many thanks

Answer (score -2):

Check any new updates for your wifi driver in Windows update or https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html and see if it works.

Or you can try to roll back to previous version of your Intel wifi driver, since it may be more stable that the current driver.

Only download from trusted sources or Official Intel Website

link: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download-center/home.html

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html

[image: 1]